# Bizarre Views and Node admin screens

Tags: 7

This is a screenshot of the content settings area of the node administration page.  MENU SETTINGS, URL REDIRECTS, XML SITEMAP, REVISION INFORMATION, META TAGS, COMMENT SETTINGS, AUTHORING INFORMATION and PUBLISHING OPTIONS content settings do not expand when clicked and cannot be edited.

[image: Node Admin Bottom]

On the Views page, the upper red box shows a series of buttons instead of the dropdown that normally houses those options.  The reason the lower red box is highlighted is that when 'Update preview' is clicked, results are shown but on another page and now below.

[image: Odd Views]

The site generally works but this all began after removing a set of popular contributed modules.  It happened on both my local site and server site so there is some consistency there.

Does anyone know what might have caused this and how it could be rectified?

Comment: Looks as if the JS stopped working, most likely due to an error; have a look in console and post the findings here.

Comment: That was it.  After changing the jQuery Update version to 1.5, everything went back to normal.  Thank you Topsitemakers!

Comment: Sure - glad it helped.